# What protections does SSL provide for a web service?

Tags: javascript, json, ssl, https, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET website that heavily uses JSON services. The basic structure is: jQuery Plugins -> JSON Service -> Server-Side BAL.

But, this solution is obviously not secure, since a malicious user can run a tool such as Fiddler and capture JSON calls on their machine, then replay these JSON calls changing parameters, etc.

If I were to put the web services folder under SSL, what protections would it give me? I tried putting the entire site under SSL, but still running Fiddler I can see clear-text messages going to HTTPS protocol, and I can replay those messages from Fiddler with the same or changed parameters.

I obviously have little knowledge about SSL and need some help. Does it sound like my SSL is not setup correctly, or being able to see SSL traffic via Fiddler is expected? If the latter, what protection does SSL provide in my scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Um, have you considered validating data on the *server* instead of just on the client?

Comment: You can configure Fiddler to decode SSL (essentially, it performs a Man-in-the-middle attack by fiddling the certificates). Your issue is not that Fiddler allows modification of parameters. Your issue is that your web-service does not perform sufficient checking and validation of the input parameters.

Comment: My web services perform checking and validation, but that's the only "line of defense" I currently have. The fact that anybody can see what parameters are sent to the server and alter the requests widens a possibility of some unforeseen attack. I wash hoping to hide request bodies, so at least it's more difficult to discover the structure of the web services.

Comment: @user1044169 It is never possible to hide outgoing communication from the client sending the communication. If you had a proprietary client, e.g. a native desktop application, it can be made somewhat more difficult with encryption. But even that's introspect-able, since the encryption code is running right on the client. It's virtually impossible to hide the structure of outgoing requests in an open, standardized system such as HTTP/Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL only encrypts the transport. Meaning a third party cannot eavesdrop on the data exchange between the client and your server. It does not add any security features to the server or service itself.

What you need is a proper authentication, permission and validation system. Every request needs to be checked for its validity. Be prepared to receive any sort of request with any sort of parameters, be that because the user fiddled with the parameters, because of a bug in your code or whatever. If a request is invalid, meaning if a particular user is not allowed to do a certain thing, reject the request.
This is not some addon technology you can implement, it's a core design consideration of your service.

Answer (score 0):

If Bob implements SSL on his website, then when Alice uses the site, then Mallory will not be able to intercept the data or alter it in-flight. SSL keeps messages between Alice's browser and Bob's server secret. It does not keep messages between Alice and Alice's browser secret.

There are two approaches you can take to protect yourself from malicious data.

1. Escape (or the equivalent) everything before inserting it into a different format. e.g. use prepared statements on SQL, build JSON with a JSON serializer and not string mashing, etc.
2. Authenticate users and only accept data from those that you trust